# Dynamic Error messages in Spring MVC3 Validation using hibernate

Tags: spring, hibernate, validation, spring-mvc

I want to be able to use a value from one form field (let's say name), if available,  in the error message of another form field (lets say email). 
For example: I want the error message for the email field to be like:
`"Hi "+name+", please enter a valid email address."`

Besides, I would also like to be able to customize error messages based on the time of the day/year, or based on other error messages.
But I've not been able to do this so far; I get this error:

```
The value for annotation attribute NotEmpty.message must be a constant expression
```

Any suggestions on how this can be done?

Answer (score 0):

```
Its due to you are using name variable in error message.
for doing this you can code at jsp page.
cutomize this by using if-else condition 
that particular error than print the given message like:
```

```
<c:if test="${success=='n'}">
      <b>put dynamic test here </b>
     <form:errors path="*"/>
</c:if>
```

where success is set at your controller like:

map.put("success", "n");

```
regards
Om
```

Comment: @Sagar Aiya:

Hello if you got problem solved than please accept.

**--Om--**